# Using Reduce Method with Express JS and Node JS

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, express, reduce

I am trying to get data from MongoDB and construct APIs to send data to my React App. Here's my code for router and app.js:

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

//import routes
const apiRoute = require('./routes/api');

app.use('/api', apiRoute);

//MONGODB CONNECTION
mongoose.connect('mongodb://**[MY LINK TO MONGODB]** },
    () => console.log('connected to real DB')
);

//LISTENING TO PORT
app.listen(5000);
```

api.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Api = require('../models/Api');

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const first_api = await Api.find({ code: 'FORM', createdDate: {
            $gte: new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 4, 16)), //since 01/05/2021
            $lte: new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 4, 31))}}, //until 31/05/2021
            ['createdDate'])
            .sort( { createdDate: -1 });

        res.json(first_api);
        console.log(first_api);
    }catch (err) {
        res.json({message: err});
    }
});
```

The format of the data "first_api" is as the following:

```
[
 {
  "code":"FORM",
  "createdDate":"2021-05-17T07:09:29.740Z"
 },
 
 {
  "code":"FORM",
  "createdDate":"2021-05-17T06:49:34.714Z"
  },
  ...
]
```

What I want to do is to add an extra function to count the number of entries with code = "FORM" per month, the expected output would be:

```
[
 {
  "January": 1,
  "February: 4,
  "March": 6,
  "April": 4,
  "May": 45,
  ...
 }
]
```

I tried to add a function using reduce method but I am not sure where should I put it in my code

```
        var string1 = JSON.stringify(first_api);
        var result = string1.reduce((r, { createdDate }) => {
            var key = new Date(createdDate).getMonth() +1;
            r[key] = (r[key] || 0) + 1;
            return result;
        }, {});
```

All I want to have is that I want the result to be sent to my React frontend as a API every time the router is called. I don't know where to insert reduce function in api.js / app.js in order to achieve my goal. Errors occurred when I inserted it in the route.get function.

FYI: I cannot use the aggregate function of MongoDB due to access right issue. I can only draw raw data from the database and do manipulation on my own.

Please help.

Comment: I would use the aggregation framework built-in in MongoDB and let mongo do the work returning only what you really need (that's an amazing part of MongoDB), and to split up the date in just the month, use the [`$month`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/) operator you can use

Comment: What was the error? And you cannot perform `reduce` on the string data type. You should directly use the data in the `first_api` and call the reduce method.

Comment: @balexandre please consider the fact that I am not the DB admin and I do not have access right to do aggregation. Do you recommend any method to achieve the same?

Comment: are you sure you can't use the [Mongoose Aggregate API](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html) to do it? I understand if you're not familiarized with the aggregation API, it's not so easy, but I'm sure with the right question you will get some great answers and help, plus, you would start see the amazing things you can do  wondering why would you need to download the whole data first and then aggregate it in the server/client... if all you can do is work like that, I'm sure a simple [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) will do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow

As I wrote as a comment, I would suggest that you leverage the amazing power of the MongoDB Aggregate API and perform all this work in the server itself, so it would be not only super-fast, but less data navigating through the wire and no more processing in the backend.

if there's no way you can do this as a MongoDB Aggregate (as you tagged Mongoose, [they have a whole section about it](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html)), you can maybe use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs), or Array.reducer(), depends on how you want the output... here's an example

```js
const data = [
    {
        "code": "FORM",
        "createdDate": "2021-05-17T07:09:29.740Z"
    },
    {
        "code": "FORM",
        "createdDate": "2021-05-17T06:49:34.714Z"
    },
    {
        "code": "FORM",
        "createdDate": "2021-01-17T06:49:34.714Z"
    },
    {
        "code": "FORM",
        "createdDate": "2021-03-17T06:49:34.714Z"
    }
];

console.log('lodash',
    _.chain(data)
        .groupBy(x => ((new Date(x.createdDate)).toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' })))
        .toPairs()
        .map(x => ({ [x[0]]: x[1].length }))
        .value()
);

console.log('reducer',
    data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        const month = (new Date(cur.createdDate)).toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
        acc[month] ? acc[month] += 1 : acc[month] = 1;
        return acc;
    }, {})
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for. But I do not know how can I do call the reduce function inside the router.get function in api.js. I would like to call data from DB, then manipulate it and finally output the result as JSON. When I try to do this, it just return error. Is it something related to nested functions?